# why I'm not able to use reduceByKey() function when using the spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Wordcount").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val textf = spark.read.textFile("in/fruits.txt")
import spark.implicits._
val textf2 = textf.flatMap( x => x.split(" ") )
val textf3 = textf2.filter ( x => x.length > 0)
val textf4 = textf3.map( x => (x,1))  // I get only reduce() function
```

why the reduceByKey is not available?.

Comment: reduceByKey is available for rdd and not for dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Dataset[String] when you read using spark session. The method reduceByKey is not available on DataSet, but it is available on RDD.
You can try this:

```
textf4.map( x => (x,1)).rdd.reduceByKey(...)
```